# Can the android sqlite interface be used outside android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Android SDK seems to have a good wrapper interfaces in package android.database.sqlite, can this wrapper (jar?) be used in for example a ms windows environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the java files for android will not work for windows, as the files are compiled to Dalvik bytecode instead of java bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many dependencies between classes like `SQLiteDatabase` and the rest of Android. You can grab the source code for those classes, hack them apart, and use them, but there may be a fair amount of hacking involved.